# Couchbase Multiple Keys

Tags: couchbase

I presume a simple question. I have the following data. [image]

I want to search for all rows where the ID is > 2 but < 8 and the Price is > 30

I have used various versions of: `startkey=["2", null]` or even something like `startkey=["2", "30"]` just for testing.

It only ever seems to run both conditions on the first row. So if I do: `startkey=["2", "30"]` then I get back:

```
{"id":"3","key":["3","30"],"value":null},
{"id":"4","key":["4","30"],"value":null},
{"id":"5","key":["5","20"],"value":null},
{"id":"6","key":["6","60"],"value":null},
{"id":"8","key":["8","60"],"value":null}
```

Why is row 5 there?

I am starting to get the view that I need to handle this in the code (.net) and make multiple calls somehow... I can't seem to find anything on this that works....

Note: I have tried doing say a loop with `for (i = 0; i < doc.ID.length; i++)` and then using `doc.ID[i]` but it never returns anything....

Currently I just have

```
function (doc, meta) {
    emit([doc.ID, doc.Price ],null);
}
```

Essentially I want to have a search where there are 5 input keys that a user has. So do I need to make 5 calls and then keep taking data from the previous output as the source for the next???

Other references I have looked at include: the manual

Thanks in advance,

Kindest Regards
Robin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common misconception, with a compound array index key, it's still treated as a string, therefore the index key [2,10] is actually "[2,10]", and the index key [5,20], is actually "[5,20]".

So the reason that `startkey=["2", "30"]`shows the `{"id":"5","key":["5","20"],"value":null},` row is because as a string it is > startkey.

Likewise, the Query `startkey=[2,10]&endkey=[5,10]` returns

```
{"total_rows":7,"rows":[
  {"id":"2","key":[2,20],"value":null},
  {"id":"3","key":[3,30],"value":null},
  {"id":"4","key":[4,30],"value":null}
  ]
}
```

because `startkey="[2,10]"` < **"[2,20]"** && **"[4,30]"** < `"[5,10]"=endkey`, but "[5,20]" is not within that string Range.

## Range Queries with startkey and endkey

**startkey** => **endkey** is a Range query using strcmp(), the group and group level is based on the string, where the comma is separating string tokens.

A Good Reference Link (since Couchbase Views work much like Apache CouchDB Views (inspired by them))
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Collation_Specification

## Spatial View/Query

To achieve the result you are trying for, you could also write a Spatial View to have multi-dimensional Queries, numeric only. While you might not initially think of it

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit({
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [doc.ID, doc.Price]
 }, meta.id);
}
```

The Query would be a Bounding Box Query:

&bbox=2,0,8,30

```
{"total_rows":0,"rows":[
  {"id":"2","bbox":[2,20,2,20],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2,20]},"value":"2"},
  {"id":"3","bbox":[3,30,3,30],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,30]},"value":"3"},
  {"id":"4","bbox":[4,30,4,30],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4,30]},"value":"4"},
  {"id":"5","bbox":[5,20,5,20],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[5,20]},"value":"5"}
]
}
```

Another Query:

&bbox=2,30,8,30

```
{"total_rows":0,"rows":[
  {"id":"3","bbox":[3,30,3,30],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[3,30]},"value":"3"},
  {"id":"4","bbox":[4,30,4,30],"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[4,30]},"value":"4"}
 ]
}
```

Comment: Hey mate. Thanks for the reading. Makes more sense now. I can get it working as expected with the numbers, but what if it really is a string. Like Spatial View only works for numbers. What if either: a) all the 'keys' are strings or b) there is a third column in the above which is a string but ID and price are numbers. Should I make a view just for the string and then join the output with the Spatial View re the numbers?

Comment: Ignore comment. Using elastic search

Comment: Is it really necessary to use elastic search?

Comment: Elastic Search allows a different set of indexing, queries, and collections/aggregations that Map/Reduce indexes (Views) do not, it's a good complement for advanced stuff.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this, but as a bit of an update re elastic, I think it is great with couchbase. I pretty much use elastic exclusively now for search and removed all views in couchbase. Elastic just returns the keys for me and then I retrieve the full document from couchbase. The whole thing is ridiculously quick and VERY flexible.